# How do I compare each row in one table with a column in another table?

Tags: sas, teradata, proc-sql

I have tables as below.

Table A(total of 3000 rows, end_date may have duplicates, ex, 123 and 223 may have the same end_date)

```
enroll_dt,end_date, acct_nbr
12/31/2016, 01/03/2017, 123
12/31/2016, 01/04/2017, 234
01/05/2017, 02/02/2017, 334
```

Table B(total of 30 unique values)

```
enroll_dt
12/31/2016
01/01/2017
01/02/2017
01/03/2017
01/04/2017
01/05/2017
...
```

Desired table:

```
Date number_of_records
12/31/2016  2
01/01/2017 2
01/02/2017 2
01/03/2017 2
01/04/2017 1
02/01/2017 1
```

What I want to do is for each value from Table B, I would sort all of rows from Table A, and return # of `acct_nbr` if 
for total # of accounts get enrolled until dateA, how many accounts have 
`end_date>DateA`. 
Ex. for `01/01/2017` from Table B, `number_of_records` = `2` since we only have 2 accounts enrolled until 01/01/2017(acct_nbr=123 and 234)
and end_date'01/03/2017' and '01/04/2017' both greater than '01/01/2017'

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: *return # of acct_nbr*: just the count of rows or count of distinct account numbers?

Comment: And how many rows exist in both tables?

Comment: Wouldn't you also want to check whether date from TableB is >= enroll_dt from TableA?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are stored as actual dates:

```
select
b.datea,
count(distinct a.acct_nbr)
from
b
inner join a
on a.end_date >= b.datea
group by 
1
```

Comment: Thanks I think it works. But I think in the original post I missed one important thing, can you take a look at the post again? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand your changes, are you looking to count only the unique acct_nbrs? If so, then use count distinct.